# Vanity wiring issue

Tags: electrical, wiring

Doing a bathroom renovation and was just looking to update fixtures and switches and ran into an issue. The box is new as I was getting shocked from the metal box that was there previously. I found the bare wire area from the previous metal clamp and shrink wrapped it. So the red wire is running from the switch box to the  vanity box (neutral), one of the black wires is running from the switch box to the vanity box. One white runs from the switch box to the vanity box. The other white and black runs to another room and powers lights and an outlet there. I can hook the black and red from the switch to the new vanity light and it will switch on and off but then my other room has no power. I connect both blacks in the vanity box and the the red to the light and it powers the other room but won't power the light for some reason. I'm lost. It was supposed to be simple.

[image: light gang box]
[image]

[image][image][image][image]

Comment: for safety that bare copper ground wire needs to be connected to the metal of both box halves,

Comment: Will do Jasen, unfortunately my problem still remains

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the vanity box please?

Comment: Its there now thanks to Kevin Reid and his helpful edit.

Comment: Can you post another angle of the inside of the switch box please? We can't really see what's going on with the left-hand switch

Comment: More photos added, the left outlet works and is grounded and it's switch to another light and a bathroom fan is functioning. The right switch bottom two switches operate lights (located in the fan) and they work as well.

Comment: With a multimeter I was able to get 120 with the switch on at the light box and nothing with it off, but when I Join the two black wires in the box I don't get 120, however as mentioned earlier the other rooms lights will work. Could the white in the vanity light box be hot? They are not labeled as such.